# How do you copy the public key to a ssh-server?

Tags: ssh

Here is what I have tried, and I got an error:

```
$ cat /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh tim@just.some.other.server 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
Password: 
cat: >>: No such file or directory
cat: .ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why not do it in two steps? Copy it across and then append it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: That works, thanks! I actually might realize the cause of trouble. Please see [my new post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29395/is-my-strange-default-shell-on-the-server-the-cause-of-my-many-troubles)?

Comment: With the -f parameter you don't need the private key, so you can just pass the key up for them with only someone's public key!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

OpenSSH comes with a command to do this, `ssh-copy-id`. You just give it the remote address and it adds your public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote machine:

```
$ ssh-copy-id tim@just.some.other.server
```

You may need to use the `-i` flag to locate your public key on your local machine:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub tim@just.some.other.server
```

Comment: Thanks! Why my command doesn't work?

Comment: @Tim [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29387/73) explained it; `>>` is handled by your shell, and you're running the command through SSH instead of through a shell. His fix of having SSH run a shell, which then runs your command, should work

Comment: Thanks! (1) ssh-copy-id doesn't work either. I manually copy the file to the remote and append its content, then it works. I wonder why is this? I found that my default shell on the server is some script, which I update to my original post, and might be the reason. Please have a look. (2) I wonder if ssh-copy-id is just copy the public key to the remote, it doesn't create the private and public key, does it?

Comment: Okay, I crated a [new post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29395/is-my-strange-default-shell-on-the-server-the-cause-of-my-many-troubles) for my default shell problem

Comment: Ah, ok. It turns out SSH does run commands through the default shell (so the method from the question would work on most machines), but your default shell is some bizarre wrapper script that doesn't handle it properly

Comment: Let's assume the SSH server is configured in such a way that it only accepts *public key authentication* as a authentication mechanism. In that case, using `ssh-copy-id` won't work, right?

Comment: @Abdull Not unless you already have some other key on that machine to connect with. It's just connecting over SSH

Answer (score 46):

You could always do something like this:

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remote.example.com:/tmp/id_rsa.pub
ssh user@remote.example.com 
cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I am not sure if you can `cat` from a local machine into an ssh session.  Just move it to /tmp as suggested.

Edit:  This is exactly what `ssh-copy-id` does.  Just like Michael said.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if ssh-copy-id is just copy the public key to the remote. It doesn't create the private and public key, does it?

Comment: No it doesn't create it.  Just adds it.

Comment: @Mr.Monkey Yes, you can pipe data into an ssh session (from `cat` or otherwise). What you're describing is the old-fashioned way; `ssh-copy-id` is recommended because there's less risk of typos or giving files wrong permissions.

Comment: @Gilles , You not always have access to the server to the client, especially when you're preparing a computer for its operation, so this method is much better than using ssh-cpy-id because you do not need to take the equipment or connect to the network before setting.

Comment: Or you can just pipe [directly to the destination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27248468/4970442): `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<hostname> 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'`.

Answer (score 10):

This answer describes how to make the intended way shown in the question working.

You can execute a shell on the remote computer to interpret the special meaning of the `>>` redirection operator:

```
ssh tim@just.some.other.server sh -c "'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'" < /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

The redirection operator `>>` is normally interpreted by a shell.

When you execute `ssh host 'command >> file'` then it is not guaranteed that `command >> file` will be interpreted by a shell. In your case `command >> file` is executed *instead* of the shell without special interpretation and `>>` was given to the command as an argument -- the same way as running `command '>>' file` in a shell.

Some versions of SSH (OpenSSH_5.9) will automatically invoke shell on the remote server and pass the command(s) to it when they detect tokens to be interpreted by a shell like `;` `>` `>>` etc.

Comment: `ssh tim@just.some.other.server 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' < /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` also work, leaving `sh -c`

Comment: @Timo Yes, I tested this between current versions of Ubuntu (OpenSSH_8.2p1) and Debian (OpenSSH_7.9p1) and it works. ...but there is some trickery: in some cases the command is run directly on the server: *`command`* in other cases it is run using shell: `bash -c ` *`command`*. I was not able to find in the OpenSSH documentation about how it is decided which way will OpenSSH use. It seems to be decided on the server side. --- To wrap it up: your shorter code might or might not work. --- I tried to explain this in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Avoiding `ssh-copy-id`

Taken from the answers/comment to the Original Poster(OP)'s question:

#### 1. with redirection (ssh at beginning)

```
ssh <user>@<host> 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

#### 2. with pipe (ssh **not** at beginning)

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<host> 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Answer (score 3):

`openssh` does provide `ssh-copy-id`. The sequence would be:

- Generate a decent 4k key

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa4k
  ```
- Start your ssh-agent up and suck in information like `SSH_AGENT_PID`, etc.

  ```
  ssh-agent -s > ~/mysshagent
  source ~/mysshagent
  rm ~/mysshagent
  ```
- Now start loading keys into your SSH Agent

  ```
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa4k
  ```
- Check that it is loaded

  ```
  ssh-add -l
  ssh-add -L
  ```

  This will show you what you have in the ssh-agent
- Now actually SSH to a remote system

  ```
  ssh username@remotehost.network
  ```
- Now you can run ssh-copy-id with no arguments:

  ```
  ssh-copy-id
  ```

  This creates `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and fills in the basic info required from ssh-agent.

Comment: BTW, I created a small script at https://github.com/centic9/generate-and-send-ssh-key which runs most of these steps in one go and additionally ensures file/directory permissions which usually always caused me headaches...

Comment: This is a great method to use when password login is disabled. It allows adding a new key while authenticating with a prior key.

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles with ssh-copy-id when choosing another port than 22...
so here is my oneliner with a different ssh-port (e.g. 7572):

```
ssh yourServer.dom -p7572 "mkdir .ssh; chmod 700 .ssh; umask 177; sh -c 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'" < .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: It works with [another port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66074/72988).

Answer (score 1):

**Indeed** the `the ssh-copy-id` command **does exactly this** (from the `openssh-client` package):

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

Note: 
`host` means *IP address* or *domain*.

---

**I would like also to add some **additional information** to this**

1) We can **specify a different port** for SSH on destination server:

```
ssh-copy-id "-p 8127 user@host"
```

Note: 
The *port* must be in front of the `user@host` or it will not resolve.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66074/185096)

2) We can **specify a file with a public key**:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host
```

Note: 
The `-i` option allows us to indicate the appropriate location of the name with the file that contains the public key.

Sometimes it can come in handy, especially if we store it in a non-standard location or we have more than one public key on our computer and we want to point to a specific one.