# Is it possible to run ssh-copy-id on port other than 22?

Tags: ssh

I have a server with SSH running on a non-standard port. Instead of 22, it runs on 8129. To log in, I use:

```
ssh -p 8129 hostname
```

Now, whenever I need to set up a key for password-less login, I have to copy the public key and add it to authorized_keys manually. I discovered that the command `ssh-copy-id` could be used to simplify this process, but it seems like it does not have an option to specify the port of the ssh server.

Is there some way to tell `ssh-copy-id` to use port 8129, or should I just forget about this command and copy/paste manually as before?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

```
$ ssh-copy-id "-p 8129 user@host"
```

***Source:*** http://it-ride.blogspot.com/2009/11/use-ssh-copy-id-on-different-port.html

**NOTE:** The port must be in front of the user@host or it will not resolve

---

**Editor's note**: as pointed out in comments and shown in [other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154406/315749), `ssh-copy-id` as shipped by more recent versions of OpenSSH supports the `-p <port_number>` syntax (no quotes needed).

Comment: It's really stupid, that `ssh` has syntax `ssh -p 1234 user@host`, `ssh-copy-id "-p 1234 user@host"` and finally `scp -P 1234 user@host`. It would be so nice to have the same syntax.

Comment: @Tombart and then rsync has `rsync -e "ssh -p 1234" user@host`. I swear it's more hassle than it's worth using a custom port.

Comment: @Colt McCormack's answer explains this is improved in new versions, and this peculiar syntax is no longer required.

Comment: FYI the full command requires the IP typed in twice, and should look something like: `ssh-copy-id "root@192.168.0.100 -p 12345" -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 192.168.0.100`

Comment: On macOS (I am on High Sierra) the quotes are not required. ie. `ssh-copy-id -p 8129 user@host` works.

Comment: RHEL7 also does not require quotes

Comment: For me it failed when I used the quotes. What worked (openssh 8.6p1-1, arch in wsl): 
`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 22222 user@192.168.0.1`

Comment: if you using Git Bash on Windows, it should be remove the double quote and event the `-i` paramter if you just have 1 ssh id : `ssh-copy-id -p {PORT} {USER}@{HOST}`,

Comment: Update: For some reason on OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, this is the syntax that works: `ssh-copy-id "-p 1234" user@host`

Answer (score 53):

`ssh-copy-id` doesn't take any arguments that it could pass down to the underlying `ssh` command, but you can configure an alias in [`~/.ssh/config`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5).

```
Host myhost
HostName hostname
Port 8129
```

Then run `ssh-copy-id myhost`.

Comment: This also has the benefit of removing the need for the `-p` flag on regular `ssh` attempts. It is therefore not only the right answer to this question, it is The Right Thing, period.

Comment: Thanks for this. The 2nd line "HostName hostname" isn't necessary if you are satisfied with the host's natural hostname.

Answer (score 30):

As of openssh-client_6.2 there is now a dedicated port flag for the command allowing for this syntax:

```
ssh-copy-id -p 8129 user@example
```

It also added support for adding other ssh options with the -o flag.

Here's is Ubuntu's man page for the appropriate version, introduced in 13.04: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/ssh-copy-id.1.html

Comment: This is the only method which worked for the.

Answer (score 11):

A quick look at the source indicates that `ssh-copy-id` appears to have no function that permits this. However, you could do something like the following instead:

```
ssh -p8129 user@host 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_*.pub
```

Answer (score 7):

This works (from [here](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2010/08/02/ubuntu-terminal-how-to-ssh-copy-id-when-the-ssh-port-is-not-21/)):

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub '-p 221 username@host'
```

Answer (score 5):

I have always used `scp` to copy it over:

```
scp -P 8129 ~/.ssh/id_*.pub user@host:
ssh -p 8129 user@host 'cat id_*.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Though I must say, I'll probably be using the other (one-line/connection) methods if I remember them in the future.  But this is another option for you.

Comment: Note scp uses uppercase -P for port, while ssh uses lower case -p. Not confusing at all.

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS7 is just:

```
 ssh-copy-id "-p 1234" user@host
```

Please take care to don't place user@host within the quotes or you'll get the following error in this distribution:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: Bad port ' 1234 user@host'
```

Answer (score 2):

There four ways to achieve this:

#### 1. Using ssh-copy-id

```bsh
ssh-copy-id -p <port> <user>@<remote-host>
```

##### 1.1 On CentOS

```bsh
ssh-copy-id "<user>@<remote-host> -p <port>"
```

#### 2. Using SSH

```bsh
ssh -p <port> <user>@<remote-host> 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_*.pub
```

#### 3. Using SCP

```bsh
scp -P <port> ~/.ssh/id_*.pub <user>@<remote-host>:
ssh -p <port> <user>@<remote-host> 'cat id_*.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

#### 4. Using `~/.ssh/config` file

```bsh
## Host <alias>
##   Hostname <remote-host>
##   Port <port>
##   User <user>
ssh-copy-id <alias>
```

Answer (score 0):

With my macOS, this worked.

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -p <port> user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this command:

`ssh-copy-id ssh://user@ip_addr:port`

Example:

`ssh-copy-id ssh://root@1.2.3.4:23`